# Unhandled Exception: UnimplementedError: RecaptchaVerifier is not implemented flutter app

Tags: flutter

i have same errors, ple help me if you fixed, but i had login ok, waiting very long time

```
E/flutter ( 3477): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(186)] Unhandled Exception: UnimplementedError: RecaptchaVerifier is not implemented
E/flutter ( 3477): #0      RecaptchaVerifierFactoryPlatform.instance (package:firebase_auth_platform_interface/src/platform_interface/platform_interface_recaptcha_verifier_factory.dart:
54:7)
E/flutter ( 3477): #1      RecaptchaVerifier._factory (package:firebase_auth/src/recaptcha_verifier.dart:11:40)
E/flutter ( 3477): #2      RecaptchaVerifier._factory (package:firebase_auth/src/recaptcha_verifier.dart)
E/flutter ( 3477): #3      new RecaptchaVerifier (package:firebase_auth/src/recaptcha_verifier.dart:56:7)
E/flutter ( 3477): #4      ApiProvider.signInWithPhoneNumber (package:clone_cgv/persistence/api_provider/api.dart:141:52)
E/flutter ( 3477): #5      Repository.signInWithPhoneNumber (package:clone_cgv/persistence/repositories/repo.dart:52:27)
E/flutter ( 3477): #6      LoginBloc.signInWithPhoneNumber (package:clone_cgv/blocs/login_blocs/bloc_login.dart:71:24)
E/flutter ( 3477): #7      _LoginPagesState._authenticateUserWithPhone (package:clone_cgv/pages/login_pages/login.dart:79:15)
E/flutter ( 3477): #8      GestureRecognizer.invokeCallback (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:182:24)
E/flutter ( 3477): #9      TapGestureRecognizer.handleTapUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:607:11)
E/flutter ( 3477): #10     BaseTapGestureRecognizer._checkUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:296:5)
E/flutter ( 3477): #11     BaseTapGestureRecognizer.acceptGesture (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:267:7)
E/flutter ( 3477): #12     GestureArenaManager.sweep (package:flutter/src/gestures/arena.dart:157:27)
E/flutter ( 3477): #13     GestureBinding.handleEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:385:20)
E/flutter ( 3477): #14     GestureBinding.dispatchEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:361:22)
E/flutter ( 3477): #15     RendererBinding.dispatchEvent (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:278:11)
E/flutter ( 3477): #16     GestureBinding._handlePointerEventImmediately (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:316:7)
E/flutter ( 3477): #17     GestureBinding.handlePointerEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:280:5)
E/flutter ( 3477): #18     GestureBinding._flushPointerEventQueue (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:238:7)
E/flutter ( 3477): #19     GestureBinding._handlePointerDataPacket (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:221:7)
E/flutter ( 3477): #20     _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1370:13)
E/flutter ( 3477): #21     _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1265:19)
E/flutter ( 3477): #22     _CustomZone.runUnaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1170:7)
E/flutter ( 3477): #23     _invoke1 (dart:ui/hooks.dart:180:10)
E/flutter ( 3477): #24     PlatformDispatcher._dispatchPointerDataPacket (dart:ui/platform_dispatcher.dart:276:7)
E/flutter ( 3477): #25     _dispatchPointerDataPacket (dart:ui/hooks.dart:96:31)
E/flutter ( 3477):
W/IInputConnectionWrapper( 3477): getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper( 3477): getSelectedText on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper( 3477): getTextAfterCursor on inactive InputConnection
E/zzf     ( 3477): Problem retrieving SafetyNet Token: 7:
I/Timeline( 3477): Timeline: Activity_launch_request time:532100882
I/zzkn    ( 3477): Provider GmsCore_OpenSSL not available
W/Activity( 3477): Slow Operation: Activity com.example.clone_cgv/com.google.firebase.auth.internal.RecaptchaActivity onResume took 123ms
W/System  ( 3477): Ignoring header X-Firebase-Locale because its value was null.
I/Timeline( 3477): Timeline: Activity_launch_request time:532102862
W/System  ( 3477): A resource failed to call end.
W/System  ( 3477): Ignoring header X-Firebase-Locale because its value was null.
W/BpBinder( 3477): Slow Binder: BpBinder transact took 268ms, interface=com.google.android.gms.auth.api.phone.internal.ISmsRetrieverApiService, code=1 oneway=false
W/System  ( 3477): Ignoring header X-Firebase-Locale because its value was null.
W/System  ( 3477): Ignoring header X-Firebase-Locale because its value was null.
D/FirebaseAuth( 3477): Notifying id token listeners about user ( oPv63pimn1au0qx8tlinSS6L69xx
```

> Blockquote

).
D/FirebaseAuth( 3477): Notifying auth state listeners about user ( oPv63pimn1au0qx8tlinSS6L69xx ).

Answer (score 9):

I guess you've tried `signInWithPhoneNumber()` on your Android mobile platform as I can see:

```
W/BpBinder( 3477): Slow Binder: BpBinder transact took 268ms,
interface=com.google.android.gms.auth.api.phone.internal.ISmsRetrieverApiService,
code=1 oneway=false
```

But unfortunately if you read the docstring (Also available at https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/auth/phone/#web-signinwithphonenumber) of `signInWithPhoneNumber()`, it says:

```
Future<ConfirmationResult> signInWithPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber, [RecaptchaVerifier? verifier])
package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart

Starts a sign-in flow for a phone number.

You can optionally provide a [RecaptchaVerifier] instance to control the reCAPTCHA widget apperance and behavior.

Once the reCAPTCHA verification has completed, called [ConfirmationResult.confirm] with the users SMS verification code to complete the authentication flow.

This method is only available on web based platforms.
```

And the last sentence,

**`This method is only available on web based platforms.`**

---

So, **IN SHORT**,

## Mobile Platform

- **`verifyPhoneNumber()`**

## Web Platform

- **`signInWithPhoneNumber()`**

**as follows: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/flutter/phone-auth**

Comment: Tks, I will try it. I will send you the answer later. Thanks a lot

Comment: @NgôMinhTrung Well it looks docs has been updated. Now, **Native Platform** : `verifyPhoneNumber`, **Web Platform** : `signInWithPhoneNumber`. Hope you've handled it!